# What is the standalone splat operator (*) used for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, splat

I just came across this example where the splat operator is used by itself in a method definition:

```
def print_pair(a,b,*)
  puts "#{a} and #{b}"
end

print_pair(1,2,3,:cake,7)
#=> 1 and 2
```

It is clear what and why you would use it in a context like so:

```
def arguments_and_opts(*args, opts)
  puts "arguments: #{args} options: #{opts}"
end

arguments_and_opts(1,2,3, a: 5)
#=> arguments: [1, 2, 3] options: {:a=>5}
```

But why and how would you use it in the first example? Since it is defined in the Ruby specs there must be a usecase for it?

Comment: where did you find such code?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko It's from this article http://www.monkeyandcrow.com/blog/the_strange_ruby_splat/, but I also found definitions like this while going through some rubygems sourcecode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a parameter list, `*args` means "gobble up all the remaining arguments in an array and bind them to the parameter named `args`". `*` means "gobble up all the remaining arguments and bind them to nothing", or put more simply "ignore all remaining arguments".

And that's exactly when you would use this: when you want to ignore all the remaining arguments. Either because you don't *care* about them, or because *you* don't care about them (but someone else might):

```
def foo(*)
  # do something
  super
end
```

Remember: `super` without an argument list passes the arguments along unmodified. So, even though *this* override of `foo` ignored the arguments, they are still available to the superclass's implementations of the method; yet, the definition makes it clear that *this* implementation doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

It is used emphasise, that method requires two arguments, but you can pass any amount (`rest` will be ignored).

You can check method's parameters with [Method#`parameters`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html#method-i-parameters):

```
method(:print_pair).parameters
#=> [[:req, :a], [:req, :b], [:rest]]
```